# Many to Many relationship Django Models with Extra Attributes

Tags: python, model-view-controller, django-models, many-to-many

i'm a beginner in Django development (and MVC programming in general!)
considering the following example how could I translate these entities into models?

USER (id, name, surname)

ENGLISH_CERTIFICATION (id, code, name)

USER_CERTIFICATION (id, id_user, id_english_certification, date)

---

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ???

class EnglishCertification(models.Model):
    code= models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ???
```

Where i put the relationships and the field "date"?
Thank you!

Comment: Does one particular `EnglishCertification` can be owned by several users?

Comment: Yes, The same "EnglishCertification" can be owned by many people!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create models that exactly represent the entities as you described, you could simply create an additional Model similar to:

```
class UserCertification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    english_certification = models.ForeignKey('EnglishCertification', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Of course you will need to adapt the code above depending on your needs. For more information you can have a look at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Hope this helps